# add connection string without using app.config

Tags: c#, subsonic, configuration-files

i created a data access layer dll using subsonic. however it uses the connectionstring from the app.config.
i am using it in ninjatrader and dont want to mess around with the ninjatrader app.config for the connecitonstring. how do i avoid this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the best you can hope for here is to use a separate file for the connection strings:

in app.config

```
<connectionStrings ConfigSource="myConnStr.config" />
```

in myConnStr.config:

```
<connectionStrings > 
  <add .... />
  <add .... />
</connectionStrings >
```

Comment: is there a way that i can force subsonic to look for connectionstring info in a xml file or programatically hardcode the connectionstring.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can set it at runtime using the [SetDefaultConnectionString](http://subsonichelp.com/html/63492ec5-4fcf-1cec-cbbd-2c4f7ee4a7a4.htm) method:

```
SubSonic.DataService.GetInstance("InstanceName").SetDefaultConnectionString("ConnectionString");
```

Comment: note... make sure to replace "ConnectionString" with your connectionstring :)

Answer (score 3):

Sample how to programatically hardcode connectionstring:

```
string connectionString = string.Format(@"Data Source={0}", Path.Combine(this.ConfigFolder, ConfigDb));
string providerName = @"System.Data.SQLite";
var provider = ProviderFactory.GetProvider(connectionString, providerName);
_configRepo = new SimpleRepository(provider, SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations);
```

This sample use sqlite database which is located in this.ConfigFolder. ConfigDB contains name of a database file.